# Problem with panelgrid not getting rerendered

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is the Visualforce code:

```
<apex:panelGrid id="pgId1" columns="13" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" styleClass="tblFilters">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Show Plan: " />
    <apex:selectList value="{!strShowPlanType}" size="1" required="true" id="slIdPlan" style="width:87px;">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ShowPlan}"/>  
        <apex:actionSupport action="{!SelectCurrentMonthQuarterYearAsDefault}" status="contentLoadingStatus" event="onchange" reRender="pgId1,slIdMonth,slIdQuarter"/>  
    </apex:selectList>

    <apex:outputLabel value="Select Quarter: " rendered="{!IF(strShowPlanType == 'Quarterly',true,false)}" /> 
    <apex:selectList value="{!strQuarter}" size="1" rendered="{!IF(strShowPlanType == 'Quarterly',true,false)}" required="true" id="slIdQuarter">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Quarter}"/>  
    </apex:selectList>

    <apex:outputLabel value="Select Month: " rendered="{!IF(strShowPlanType == 'Monthly',true,false)}" /> 
    <apex:selectList value="{!strMonth}" size="1" required="true" id="slIdMonth" rendered="{!IF(strShowPlanType == 'Monthly',true,false)}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Month}"/>  
    </apex:selectList>

    <apex:outputLabel value="Select Year: "/ > 
    <apex:selectList value="{!strYear}" size="1" required="true" id="slIdYear" style="width:81px;">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Year}"/>  
    </apex:selectList>
```

Here is the corresponding apex action function called by actionsupport:

```
public pageReference SelectCurrentMonthQuarterYearAsDefault()
{
    System.debug('---Called!!---');
    Date currentDate = system.today();

    strMonth = mapFullNameofMonth.get(currentDate.month());
    strYear = string.valueOf(currentDate.Year());

    integer quarterNo = integer.valueOf(math.ceil(decimal.valueOf(currentDate.month()) / 3.0));
        strQuarter = quarterNo == 1 ? 'First Quarter' : (quarterNo == 2 ? 'Second Quarter' : (quarterNo == 3 ? 'Third Quarter' : 'Fourth Quarter'));    
    system.debug('NRAC:QN:'+quarterNo);
    return null;
}
```

SelectMonth label& selectlist not getting rendered after selecting show plan value as 'Monthly'.

Comment: Added outputpanel before panelgrid...tried to rerender it on selecting plan;not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has reasons of not working.

When you use `actionSupport` function for first `selectList` it will call controller method. **Now during execution, property values are assigned first, followed by method call**.

Now, think of the scenario, you are selecting the first `selectList` and at that moment all these mandatory fields have not been entered, so `actionSupport` will not get executed properly.

> So, either you can remove `required` attribute from the page or use `actionFunction` instead of `actionSupport` to pass value to controller or performing any action.

Answer (score 0):

Removed required=true from selectlist...working now..Don't know the reason why it worked!